# qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found. in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qmake

How should I solve this problem in Ubuntu 20.04?

```
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyqt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

 

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.

 

Aborted (core dumped)
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyqt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

 

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.

 

Aborted (core dumped)
2224/31772MB(vision)
```

and

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
:0
```

and

```
$ python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import inspect
>>> from PyQt5 import Qt
>>> vers = ['%s = %s' % (k,v) for k,v in vars(Qt).items() if k.lower().find('version') >= 0 and not inspect.isbuiltin(v)]
>>> print('\n'.join(sorted(vers)))
PYQT_VERSION = 331522
PYQT_VERSION_STR = 5.15.2
QOpenGLVersionProfile = <class 'PyQt5.QtGui.QOpenGLVersionProfile'>
QOperatingSystemVersion = <class 'PyQt5.QtCore.QOperatingSystemVersion'>
QT_VERSION = 331522
QT_VERSION_STR = 5.15.2
QVersionNumber = <class 'PyQt5.QtCore.QVersionNumber'>
```

As a minimal code to reproduce this error, you can run this:

```
$ cat test_qt.py 
'''
====================
3D plots as subplots
====================

Demonstrate including 3D plots as subplots.
'''

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D, get_test_data
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np


# set up a figure twice as wide as it is tall
fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(0.5))

#===============
#  First subplot
#===============
# set up the axes for the first plot
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1, projection='3d')

# plot a 3D surface like in the example mplot3d/surface3d_demo
X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
Z = np.sin(R)
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
ax.set_zlim(-1.01, 1.01)
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=10)

#===============
# Second subplot
#===============
# set up the axes for the second plot
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2, projection='3d')

# plot a 3D wireframe like in the example mplot3d/wire3d_demo
X, Y, Z = get_test_data(0.05)
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, rstride=10, cstride=10)

plt.show()

$ python test_qt.py 
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyqt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Also,

```
$ python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
>>>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First do this:

```
$  export DISPLAY=:1.0
```

The newest version of opencv-python that I had installed was causing the problem with pyqt5. So I uninstalled it and installed the following version:

```
$ pip install opencv-python==4.3.0.36
```

Adding the following info in case it might help future readers.

Here's my pyqt version:

```
$ pip list|grep Qt
PyQt5                  5.15.2
PyQt5-sip              12.8.1


$ python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux

$ pip --version
pip 21.0 from /home/mona/venv/vision/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63350799/2414957